# Plugin Failing on D365 v9 Online when I just have tracers to test execution

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, workflow, dynamics-crm-365-v9

I did a build for a custom wf assembly in VS 2017.

The following is my code.  There is no red squigglies and registered without error:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Activities;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;

namespace CustomerAsset
{
    public partial class CustomerAsset : CodeActivity
    {

        //public InArgument<EntityReference> CustomerAsset { get; set; }
        protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext executionContext)
        {

            //Create the tracing service
            ITracingService tracer= executionContext.GetExtension<ITracingService>();
            tracer.Trace("Begin Plugin Execution");
            //Create the context
            IWorkflowContext context = executionContext.GetExtension<IWorkflowContext>();
            IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = executionContext.GetExtension<IOrganizationServiceFactory>();
            IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

            try
            {
                //DO WORK HERE
                Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

                var targetCustAssOpHrsId = entity.Id;
                tracer.Trace(entity.LogicalName);
                tracer.Trace(targetCustAssOpHrsId.ToString());

                QueryExpression qe = new QueryExpression();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("error in CustomerAsset custom workflow assembly");
                //throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The following is what I already attempted:

- Recompiled to .NET 4.5.2
- Ensured targeting core assemblies to correct version of d365 v9 online

Is there any other gotchas?  Im using dev guide rather than previous SDK so this is a bit new to me.

As you can see from code. I am just tracing.  I threw a trace write after instanciating tracer and doesn't even get to that.

Also note, Im running this on-demand to test execution.

Comment: .NET 8.5.2?! Living in the future :)

Comment: @jasonscript edited to reflect 4.5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check if the Plugin Tracing setting is set to "All".

(Settings > Administration > System Settings > Customization)

[image: screenshot]

You could also try throwing an exception in the code to see if that registers.

After updating the Plugin Assembly in D365, check the solution to ensure that the ModifiedOn has changed.

Comment: You my friend, are a force to be reckoned with.  That solved my prob.

Comment: I've instructed the JRs to do the following so they don't pull the last of their hair out lol:             ITracingService tracer= executionContext.GetExtension<ITracingService>();
            try
            {
                tracer.Trace("");
            }
            catch
            {
                tracer.Trace("----------------------------------------");
                tracer.Trace("TURN ON TRACE LOGS IN SYSTEM SETTINGS!!!");
                tracer.Trace("----------------------------------------");
            }